# How do I tell if a function is tail recursive C?

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list, tail-recursion, tail

Is my function here a tail recursion? If so why/ why not? I have some trouble grasping the concept so any help is much appreciated.

```
struct link 
{
  int value; //data    
  link_t *next; //link
};

struct list
{
    link_t *first;
    link_t *last;
};


int list_size_count(link_t *first, int acc)
{
  if (first != NULL)
  {
    return (acc + list_size_count((first->next), 1));
  }
  return acc;
}

int linked_list_size(list_t *list)
{
  return list_size_count((list->first),0);
}
```

Comment: What do you think? What conclusions do you draw? What effort have you put into it?

Comment: In general, a [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) is when the return value of a function is the *direct* result of another function call, with the returned value being passed *directly* as the new return value.  This raises the opportunity to perform tail-call optimization, where the called function returns directly to the calling function's caller.  This allows the current stack frame to be reclaimed *before* the function is called. But this only happens if your compiler supports tail-call optimization.

Comment: In your posted code, the only tail call is in `linked_list_size`, which calls and returns the result of `list_size_count`.  The recursive function `list_size_count` does not contain a tail call (so is not tail-recursive).  It could be transformed into a tail-recursive function by folding the add of `acc` into the function itself, so that the return value does not need to be modified in the caller before being returned.

Comment: What's more important is if the compiler can actually optimize the recursion. Generally, compilers can only do that if it's tail call recursion. Meaning that any recursion which isn't tail call should never be used in any circumstances, because it is very slow, very dangerous and generally unreadable. This for absolutely nothing gained.

Comment: @TomKarzes How do I do that?

Comment: @davdavdav2 Look at the answer posted by anton-tchekov.  It shows how to transform `list_count_size` into an equivalent tail-recursive function.  Notice that the new function returns the result of the recursive call *directly*, without changing it.  That makes it possible for the called function to return directly to the calling function caller (again, if your compilter's optimizer performs tail-call optimization).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a function to be tail recursive, the recursive call must be its last action.
In your code, the last thing the function does is adding two values, so `list_size_count()` is not tail recursive.

```
int list_size_count(link_t *first, int acc)
{
  if (first != NULL)
  {
    return (acc + list_size_count((first->next), 1));
  }
  return acc;
}
```

Here is how to make it tail recursive:

```
int list_size_count(link_t *first, int acc)
{
  if(first != NULL)
  {
    return list_size_count(first->next, acc + 1);
  }

  return acc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the final action of a routine is to call another routine, it is called a *tail call*. An example is a routine, say a routine named `g`, that ends with `return f(x);`. The straightforward way to compile this code is:

- Pass the argument `x` by copying it to the designated place to pass an argument.
- Execute a subroutine call instruction to call `f`.
- Clean up the stack frame (as by restoring the stack pointer to the value it had when this routine started executing) and execute a return instruction.

Because this is the last thing the routine `g` is going to do, we do not need `f` to return to `g`. Instead of calling it, we can jump to it:

- Copy `x` to where an argument is passed.
- Execute a branch instruction to jump to `f`.

Then `f` will execute, clean up the stack frame we are currently in, and execute a return instruction. That will return to `g`’s caller, as if `g` had executed a return instruction. We get the same effect from these instructions as from the earlier instructions but with less work.

(There are further details not shown here. For this to work, the rules about managing stack frames have to allow `f` to clean up the stack frame of `g`, even though `f` may also establish its own context on the stack.)

If `f` and `g` are the same routine, this is called *tail recursion*.

Note that, in this example, `f` and `g` must return the same type of data. If `f` returns a `float` and `g` returns an `int`, then, when `g` contains `return f(x);`, calling `f` is not actually the last thing `g` does. There is an automatic conversion from `float` to `int` in the `return` statement, so that would not be a tail call.

A tail call just has to be the last action of a routine; it does not have to be the last source code in a routine. If `return f(x);` appears anywhere in the routine (and the types match), that is a tail call, and it can be replaced by a branch (if the stack management rules permit). Also, if the return type of `g` is void, then `f(x); return;` anywhere in the routine is a tail call, and `f(x);` at the end of the routine is a tail call.

In your routine `linked_list_size`, `return list_size_count((list->first),0);` is a tail call, but it is not tail recursion.

In your routine `list_size_count`, there is no tail call because, in `return (acc + list_size_count((first->next), 1));`, the `+` is executed after the call to `list_size_count`. You can make it a tail call, and tail recursion, by rewriting it to:

```
return list_size_count(first->next, acc+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is my function here a tail recursion?

No it's not.

This line

```
return (acc + list_size_count((first->next), 1));
```

includes an add operation **after** the recursive call returns, i.e. an add of `acc` and whatever the recursive call returns. Consequently it's not a tail recursion.

But it's easy to turn into tail recursion. Simply change the above line to:

```
++acc;
return list_size_count((first->next), acc);
```

Here `acc` is incremented first and passed as argument to the recursive function and the result of the recursive call is used directly in the return statement.

Now there is no operation after the recursive call. Consequently it's tail recursion.